# How to build Quarkus container based on profile with Gradle?

Tags: gradle, quarkus

8.1

I'm able to build my container image with Jib running: `./gradlew clean build -Dquarkus.container-image.build=true`

And then I can run it with `docker run`

The container built is running using the production profile.

I have a separate dev/staging container environment, where I can actually deploy and obviously the configs for passwords and domains are different.

Is there a way to specify the profile during the container build, so for example when it runs it uses the dev profile configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick:

`./gradlew clean build -Dquarkus.container-image.build=true -Dquarkus.profile=dev`